# GridView HeaderStyle property not working?

Tags: asp.net

This is a simple question. In a GridView control, I assumed that I could set the  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold item within the asp:GridView tag and it would automatically apply it to all column header texts but this has no effect and only works if I set it within the asp:BoundField tag of each column.

This doesnt work:

```
<asp:GridView ... HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false">
```

but this does:

```
<asp:BoundField ... HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false"/>
```

Is this how its suppose to work? ie do I have to set the headerstyle at each column?
What effect should it have if I set the HeaderStyle-Font-Bold in the asp:Griview tag?

Thanks

Rob

### Edit

I'm not looking for a solution as to how to make the header text bold as I already know how to do this. My question is about using the HeaderStyle-Font-Bold property and why it doesnt work if I set it in the asp:griview tag but works fine in the asp:BoundField tag.

Thanks

Comment: Your gridview must have some CssClass="someclass" . Or you must have using some stylesheet with default tags like table{} or tr{} td{} . So they are enforcing their own styles on your inline one. Check using firebug or developer tools to find underlying styles on controls

Comment: I've checked my style tag to see if I have setup a style for table headers but theres nothing there. I've also linked in the jquery smoothness stylesheet but I dont think that would affect my gridview

Answer (score 5):

Add class to `Gridview Control` work both for using `ItemTemplate,BoundField` and set css

**HTML MARKUP:**

```
 <asp:GridView  CssClass="gvstyling">
  ....
</asp:GridView>
```

**Simple CSS:**

```
// For heading
      .gvstyling th {
            background-color: Red;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
// For Cell
    .gvstyling td {
                background-color: Red;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
// For Row
    .gvstyling tr {
                background-color: Red;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
```

---

Answer to yours edited one

If you using TemplateField, then you need to Add `HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false"` inside `TemplateField` instead of `Gridview` and it will work for you

**HTML MARKUP:** look like this

```
<asp:GridView id="myGV1" CssClass="gvstyling">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

   ......
   ......
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: If you have 20 columns, you will need to copy 'HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false"' to all fields.  Which is exactly why it would be nice to declare the style only once.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
<headerstyle 
        font-bold="false"/>
```